# What exactly does "oldClass()' method do and how can it be useful?

Tags: r, class, oop

Besides regular `class()` there exists another method named `oldClass()`. However, the documentation pages of `help(oldClass)` never mention what that method does. It only states that `oldClass()` behaves like the `oldClass()` method from S-PLUS 5.

What is the purpose of `oldClass()` and where should it be used instead of regular `class()` ?

Comment: As the help page says, "Functions `oldClass` and `oldClass<-` get and set the [class] attribute, which can also be done directly."

Comment: @user2554330 `class` and `class<-` also get and set [class] attribute, with the seeming exception that `class` sometimes takes `type` as a class too. I think a concrete example of where one should use `oldClass` instead of `class` would answer this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the docs say, `oldClass()` retrieves the `"class"` attribute of an object, whereas `class()` may also construct something based on the base type of the object.  For example,

```r
x <- 1:10
oldClass(x)
#> NULL
class(x)
#> [1] "integer"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

One use for this is when you are modifying the class of an object, as you might do if you have added a special attribute, or want to indicate that it has some special meaning.  It will be a tiny bit inefficient to use `class()` instead of `oldClass()`, and usually you wouldn't want `"integer"` to be part of the class attribute.

You will also see differences in `inherits()`:

```r
x <- 1:10
class(x) <- c("newclassname", class(x))
oldClass(x)  # equivalent to attr(x, "class")
#> [1] "newclassname" "integer"
inherits(x, "integer")
#> [1] TRUE

y <- 1:10
oldClass(y) <- c("newclassname", oldClass(y))
oldClass(y)
#> [1] "newclassname"
inherits(y, "integer")
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

However, for most purposes, it doesn't really matter whether you use `class()` or `oldClass()`.